# Difficulty in aligning child to the mostleft and mostright in-between another child

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I want two images to be displayed on left and right and a textview in between them just at small distance to the left image but I couldn't get it done.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_of_services"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_of_services"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="adasdsad"
    android:layout_weight="8"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what was your actual need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_of_services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_of_services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="adasdsad"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i have edited the code and it worked perfectly as i desired

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_of_services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_of_services"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="adasdsad"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</LinearLayout>`
```